# Passing Variables between Visual Basic 2015 and Python

Tags: python, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am working on code in Visual Basic 2015 that is calling a Python 2.7 program.  Right now I am trying to pass a variable, "arg1= 1" from VB to Python.  This is the VB code:

```
Private Sub FWHM_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FWHM.Click
    Dim pythonProcess As New Process()
    Dim arg1 As New Integer
    arg1 = 1
    With pythonProcess
        .StartInfo.FileName = "pythonw.exe"
        .StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Users\...\"
        .StartInfo.Arguments = ("HelloWorld.py" & arg1)
        .StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        .StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        .Start()
    End With
End Sub
```

As you can see the code activates when the I click a button in my form.  The button works fine when I don't try to pass "arg1", as the python code shows me a window with a sinusoidal graph.  arg1's value will change the period of the sinusoidal graph.

This is the Python code, and it is pretty simple.  I am just starting to learn to use Python.  I am not in the process of learning Python, just for learning it. I just need Python to perform some mathematical libraries that will be eventually used in the VB program:

```
from sys import argv

script = argv

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

msg= script
msg= "Hello Wolrd"
print(msg)
arg1= 1
x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x*arg1))
plt.show()
```

I eventually want to pass a pointer to Python as I am going to pass an array, and I assume and array is easier to pass as a pointer if it is about 100x100 floats.

Comment: You've got the arguments in `sys.argv`, which you assign to `script`, and then to `msg`… but then you immediately replace that with `"Hello Wolrd"`. Why do you do that? Try just `print(msg)` without that, and you'll be able to see what you actually got.

Answer (score 0):

Your VB code is just passing `1` as a command-line argument, which is fine—although you may need to change it to add a space after the script name.

So, in your Python code, [`sys.argv[1]`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) will be the string `"1"`, because that's the string representation of the number `1`.

You can convert that back into a number with `int` or `float` (depending on whether it's always going to be an integer, or may be something like `1.5`).

For some reason, you've copied `argv` into another variable named `script`, and then into another one named `msg`, and then ignored it, replaced `msg` with the string `"Hello Wolrd"`, and just assigned the constant `1` to `arg1`. Instead of all that, do this:

```
from sys import argv
arg1 = float(argv[1])
```

That's it.

But…

> I eventually want to pass a pointer to Python as I am going to pass an array, and I assume and array is easier to pass as a pointer if it is about 100x100 floats.

That you can't do. Command-line arguments can only be a few short-ish strings, not giant things, and not thing you can't easily convert to and from a string, and definitely not pointers into your own memory.

What you usually want to do in that case is either:

1. Have VB export the array as a file in some nice format (like CSV or JSON), pass the filename as a command-line argument, and have Python import the array from the file.
2. Have VB convert the array to a string in some nice format and pass it as the standard input to Python, and have Python parse it from `sys.stdin`.

The first one is probably a bit simpler (because you don't have to learn how to write to the stdin pipe of a child process). I don't know how to write the VB side of that, but the Python side would look like this:

```
import json
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as f:
    arr = json.load(f)
```

And then, if you want to, say, convert that from a list of lists into a numpy 2D array, you do it the same as for any other value:

```
arr = np.array(arr)
```

Comment: It does makes sense in the pyhton side.  I do believe that my implementation of passing the arguments in VB are incorrect.  If  is write this:   .StartInfo.Arguments = "HelloWorld.py"  the python code works as expected.  But if I write this:    .StartInfo.Arguments = ("HelloWorld.py" & arg1) then the python code does not work at all.

Comment: @alvaro You may just be missing a space there between the script name and the argument? Or maybe `Arguments` is supposed to be an array rather than a string?

Comment: So you are correct on the last statement in a weird way.  If I write the code like this:   .StartInfo.Arguments = ("HelloWorld.py" & "1.00")  it doesn't work.  Notice that I am explicitly writing the variable as a string.  But If I write it as this:  .StartInfo.Arguments = ("HelloWorld.py 1.00") or even like this: .StartInfo.Arguments = ("HelloWorld.py 1") it works ok and I can convert the string of the second arg to a float and use it in my calculations

Comment: For Continuity sake, this is what the code looks like now--> I changed arg1 to double: Dim arg1 As New Double   Then you were right about the space.  It goes at the end in the call on the python script:  .StartInfo.Arguments = ("HelloWorld.py " & arg1).  And now the python code works fine.  Now I need to figure out the best way to pass the array.  Thanks again

Comment: @alvaro Are you using any kind of .NET array-processing library? Because they probably have built-in functionality to export to strings or files in standard formats like CSV or JSON. If not, I've used [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) from C#, and it should be just as easy to use from VB—if your array is just a native array of arrays of floats, you can just call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arr)`.

Comment: @alvaro If your arrays were _huge_ it might be worth learning about shared memory—but for 100x100, passing it as JSON or CSV through a file or stdin is more than good enough, and a lot simpler.

Comment: That is what I am thinking.  Probably save a file with the array, and then open it with the other program.  I don't even need to send the file name as an argument, but maybe it is safe to do it.  However, I may explore the other options, just in case I want to learn these other approaches.  Thanks again.